# Advanced Installer Working in appdata

Tags: java

I have a simple reporting java application that is using jre archive,h2database and jasper repor.

The database file location is : appdir\files\db\tbs.mv.db
The Jasper file Jrxml file location is : appdir\files\report.jrxml

Basically i want to move the DB file to %appdata% folder so that it does not require administrator access to write to the h2database file.

In Advanced Installer Files and Folder>>Application Data
I added the folder **files** . Database connection working fine but not the jasper jrxml file.

Anyone can instruct me in details that how i can make my application work in %appdata% with Advanced Installer?

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. However we don't edit titles to do that here - please self-accept your answer, by clicking the adjacent tick mark. Cheers!

Comment: Okay, I am waiting for tomorrow

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was forgot catch exception. The jrxml file was not found.

Problem is solved!